# Converting data from NASA's Trajectory Browser into state vectors

Tags: orbital-mechanics

I've found this super awesome tool, provided by NASA, called Trajectory Browser. I would like to simulate some of the trajectories listed there but can't quite figure out how to convert the trajectory data into state vectors, or if it's even possible. More specifically, I'm looking at [this](https://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/traj_browser.php?NEAs=on&NECs=on&chk_maxMag=on&maxMag=25&chk_maxOCC=on&maxOCC=4&chk_target_list=on&target_list=Venus&mission_class=roundtrip&mission_type=flyby&LD1=2015&LD2=2030&maxDT=1.2&DTunit=yrs&maxDV=7.0&min=DV&wdw_width=365&submit=Search#a_load_results) trajectory.

Bit lost, so if somebody could lend me a helping hand, that would be super awesome!

Comment: Sometimes all you have to do is click view source to get the answer to your question; https://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/javascript/traj_lib.js

Comment: Should be able to work with that, so please ignore my question.

Comment: You should expand your comment into an answer, with as much explanation of what you found as you have the patience to give.

Comment: @HappyKoala I agree, can you post a short answer and explain what you found? Thanks!

Comment: Hey fellows, yes, I most certainly will. Will take a couple of days, though, but as sooner as I've teased out what's going on in the code I linked to, I'm gonna come bouncing back here and hopefully shed some light on the matter for others that might be interested!

Comment: FYI: the code was not enough as the trajectory calculations were done server side, but a collaborator is now working on developing a lambert solver and once he's done I will ask him to provide an answer here. Thanks for your patience!